# Conversion System.Windows.Media.Geometry --> System.Drawing.Region

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing, drawing2d

I have an unmanaged API, which uses a `System.Drawing.Region` as argument.

The problem is, that I have a `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`, which I need to convert into the `Region`-class.

I wonder how I should convert this type...
Should I look for corner points and convert them or does already a conversion method exist *[which I did not yet find]*?

---

If someone needs an example for a `System.Windows.Media.Geometry`, the XAML-code looks as following:

```
<GeometryGroup>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="32,0,440,89"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,89,472,41"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="472,93,66,193"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="53,130,419,156"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="53,184,38,102"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="91,200,52,86"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="143,216,75,70"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="218,232,52,54"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="270,248,75,38"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="345,264,52,22"/>
    <RectangleGeometry Rect="516,270,22,16"/>
<GeometryGroup/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I found the solution by myself:

```
Geometry geo = .... ;

IEnumerable<PolyLineSegment> segments =
    from PathFigure figure in geo.GetOutlinedPathGeometry().Figures
    from PathSegment segment in figure.Segments
    select s as PolyLineSegment;

using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
{
    path.StartFigure();

    foreach (PolyLineSegment plseg in segments)
    {
        PointF[] points = (from point in plseg.Points
                           select new Point((float)point.X, (float)point.Y)).ToArray();

        path.AddPolygon(points);
    }

    path.CloseFigure();

    // DO SOMETHING WITH `path´
}
```